# mysql database is not being seeded by spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

According to this tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql
Spring Boot is supposed to look for a file called data.sql and execute it, which will seed the database.  I have created that file with a bunch of sql insert statements but the database tables remain empty.  Spring boot successfully created the tables from the models, so that at least worked.

I have the file located in a db subpackage under the main package.  Suggestions?

My application.properties has the following:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you can create a data.sql file under src/main/resources folder.

Hope this helps

Comment: I moved data.sql into src/main/resources but still the tables are empty after new run.  I've updated my question with some more details.

Comment: You also need to add spring.batch.initialize-schema=always to your application.properties file.  Then it works.

Comment: I would also add that you better change from update to create if you want ALL changes you've made to the model schemas to get implemented.  ie. spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create   If you change from varchar(16) to varchar(32), for example, the change will NOT be updated in the table!

Comment: Great. If you want something more flexible you can try Flyway.

Comment: Yea, with hibernate now set to create instead of update, it re-created tables that I didn't want it to touch.  Even with @Immutable applied to the table!  How can anybody figure out all these rules!